# Generating set of a complex lattice contains a basis

Tags: complex-numbers, modules, integer-lattices

Let $\Gamma\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a lattice, i.e. a set of the form $\gamma_1\mathbb{Z}+\gamma_2\mathbb{Z}$ where the set of complex numbers $\{\gamma_1, \gamma_2\}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent. Suppose $S\subset \Gamma$ is a finite generating set of $\Gamma$. Does there always exist a subset of $S$ that is a basis of $\Gamma$ (i.e. an $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent generating set)?

Comment: Since $\Gamma$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module, the word basis is maybe not the right one. Anyways... Consider $\Gamma =\Bbb Z^2$ instead. And since there are two directions, we may maybe want to see what happens with $\Bbb Z$ instead. Then $2,3$ are generating $\Bbb Z$, but no single element choice does. (Add now an easy generator for the other direction to have a counterexample for $\Bbb Z^2\cong \Gamma$.)